# Query to use when I know a Defect and want to search if a UserStory associated with it

Tags: java, rally

I am writing in Java and have already retrieved a JsonArray of Defect items from Rally.  Now I want to be able to get only those User Stories that have one of the Defects I got associated with them.  I have been unable to come up with a good query to do this, and currently I am getting all the User Stories and then looking through their Defects field to see if one of the defects I had is a member.

Can anyone suggest a query that would allow me to directly get the story that goes with a defect?  Thanks.

Comment: query as in sql style query? or standard java? I don't know what rally is.

Comment: If you read the description on the tag he is using that can give you some more information on what Rally is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to specify a fetch that will pull the fields you need from the story and attach them to the defect.

```
fetch=Requirement,Name,Iteration,ScheduleState
```

That would hydrate all of those fields on the story (Requirement) as well as the Defect.

```
{
    Defect: {
        _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/defect/5678.js",
        Name: "Sad Pandas",
        Iteration: null,
        Requirement: {
            _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/hierarchicalrequirement/1234.js",
            _refObjectName: "Pandas",
            Name: "Pandas",
            Iteration: null,
            ScheduleState: "In-Progress",
            Blocked: false,
            _type: "HierarchicalRequirement"
        },
        ScheduleState: "Idea",
        Blocked: false,
        Errors: [ ],
        Warnings: [ ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly, putting "Requirement" as the first item in fetch will make it so that the fetch fields listed after it will be pulled for both the Requirement and Defect?

Comment: Nope, their order is not important. Putting Requirement in the Fetch will have the WSAPI return the story that is attached to the Defect. In addition it will populate each field in the fetch collection for each subobject on the Defect.
So the Defect will have it's Name populated for itself and all it's child objects. But this hydration will only go one level deep so the objects on Story will stay unhydrated.

Comment: Thanks this really helped and made my life a little easier not having to sort through a whole lot of UserStories.  As a follow up, is it possible to do something similar in javascript with the app sdk?  As I understand it right now it is not, the parameters you set for fetch in a config only get the top level results, like what would be seen by looking at the JSON result

Comment: The JavaScript SDK and the Java SDK hit the same endpoints. You can do the same things with both. I hit the endpoint raw to get the test data I provided above.